# How to load a WMTS layer in QGIS using PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, wmts

I've found tons of topics about how to load a WMS layer in PyQGIS, but nothing about WMTS. 
In the GUI, adding a WMS or a WMTS layer is done by clicking the same button so I expect the syntax to be close, but I failed to figure it out entirely.

So I took this url ([from this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137032/can-qgis-2-8-load-wmts-layers)) to make my testing :

```
http://opencache.statkart.no/gatekeeper/gk/gk.open_wmts?Version=1.0.0&service=wmts&request=getcapabilities
```

It works if you try to add layers from this source using the GUI.
I tried to copy [the syntax that allows to add a WMS layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116238/wms-layer-in-a-qgis-2-4-stand-alone-python-script) (so I added needed parameters like layers=, format=, style=) but my layer is never valid.

```
layer = QgsRasterLayer('url=http://opencache.statkart.no/gatekeeper/gk/gk.open_wmts?&layers=barentswatch_stedsnavn&Version=1.0.0&service=wmts&format=image/jpeg&styles=', 'anytitle', 'wms')
layer.isValid()
>> False
```

Does somebody see the mistake / know the trick (or where I can find documentation about it) ?

Comment: In geoserver the url looks like this:

http://serverName/geoserver.com/gwc/service/wms?tiled=true

Maybe yours is something like this:

http://opencache.statkart.no/gatekeeper/gk/wms?tiled=true

Comment: Each software has got his own syntax regarding OGC services. PyQGIS is quite capricious and only tolerates specific syntaxes (at least, that is what I observed from working with WFS and WMS). So it is normal that the url I built doesn't look like a geoserver one. 
Nevertheless, I tried to add the "tiled=true" and switch the 'wmts' parameter to 'wms' but without success. 
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

AS [WMTS standard (p59)](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wmts) says (or [here in French](https://georezo.net/wiki/main/standards/wmts)), **tileMatrixSet** is a required parameter, at least for a client like QGIS which manage the rest of things.

Among things that are good to know, there is no "wmts" option in *QgsRasterLayer* method. You've have to set "wms". And the request to pass to QGIS is not GetTile, but GetCapabilities. QGIS does its own soup after that.

To perform my tests, I wrote a [short script that can be executed in QGIS Python console](https://github.com/isogeo/isogeo-plugin-qgis/blob/master/tests/dev/qgis_console/dev_wmts.py). Tested on 2.14.x and 2.18.x. I can't guarantee that's work with every WMTS service. Some GetCapabilities return bad encoding XML.

Comment: the link to the script doesn't exist anymore, please provide code directly in the answer

Comment: I just updated the missing link.